# Tuple index put of range?

Tags: python

While i was trying to build a tic tac toe game and i wanted to test my function for displaying the board. It gave me 'tuple index out of range' error constantly so i changed it to the simplest form, i simply put a list in the format method:

```
print(' {7} | {8} | {9} \n ------------ \n {4} | {5} | {6} \n ----------- \n {1} | {2} | {3} '.format(['#','X','O','X','O','X','O','X','O','X']))
```

the list has 10 elements. And there is no tuple in sight i am a beginner in python and i am currently very struggling with this.

Comment: Hi, could you please post your code as well?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, you are giving `format` a single argument - a list with ten elements.

Give `format` ten arguments by unpacking the list or not using a list at all.

with unpacking:

```
>>> print(' {7} | {8} | {9} \n ------------ \n {4} | {5} | {6} \n ----------- \n {1} | {2} | {3} '.format(*['#','X','O','X','O','X','O','X','O','X']))
 X | O | X 
 ------------ 
 O | X | O 
 ----------- 
 X | O | X
```

without unpacking:

```
>>> print(' {7} | {8} | {9} \n ------------ \n {4} | {5} | {6} \n ----------- \n {1} | {2} | {3} '.format('#','X','O','X','O','X','O','X','O','X'))
 X | O | X 
 ------------ 
 O | X | O 
 ----------- 
 X | O | X
```

Answer (score 0):

`.format` works without list.

```
print(' {7} | {8} | {9} \n ------------ \n {4} | {5} | {6} \n ----------- \n {1} | {2} | {3} '.format(
        '#', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'X'))
```

Answer (score 0):

`.format` expects individual arguments, not an iterable. You need to unpack the list into separate args using the `*` operator.

```
print(' {7} ...'.format(*['#','X','O','X','O','X','O','X','O','X']))
#                       ^ here
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a single argument to `format`. Remove the list `[ ]` to pass ten arguments.

Or you can use `*` unpacking operator to unpack one iterable sequence into multiple arguments.

```
print(
  ' {7} | {8} | {9} \n'
  '-----------\n'
  ' {4} | {5} | {6} \n'
  '-----------\n'
  ' {1} | {2} | {3} '.format(*'#XOXOXOXOX')
)
```